# link css and javascript to xcode iphone app

Tags: javascript, css, xcode, hyperlink

I have copy and pasted the css and js files for Copy Bundle Resources and removed them from Compile Sources.

How do I "link" or "import" them so I can use the css and javascript files?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have the right links to your css & javascript files when you move them into your xcode project. If and when you have made a project in xcode, you should be able to view your project directory in finder. From there, navigate to the www folder and make sure that all of your code is pasted into this folder. Also, make sure that your home page is named "index.html" as this is how xcode will find the correct html page to display upon booting.